# Error connecting to IBM MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

When I execute the code below, I get the following error. Could you tell me why, please? It sounds the problem is with the channel, but I verified and I didn't identified the cause of the problem. I tried many examples from the web, but this problem still remains.

```
   import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.ibm.mq.MQAsyncStatus;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueue;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants;

public class MQClientTest2 {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQClientTest.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Create a connection to the queue manager
        Hashtable<String, Object> props = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
        props.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "WM.SVRCONN.001");
        props.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
        props.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "localhost");

        String qManager = "QM1";
        String queueName = "LQ1";
        MQQueueManager qMgr = null;
        try {
            qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, props);

            // MQOO_OUTPUT = Open the queue to put messages. The queue is opened for use with subsequent MQPUT calls.
            // MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF = Open the queue to get messages using the queue-defined default.
            // The queue is opened for use with subsequent MQGET calls. The type of access is either
            // shared or exclusive, depending on the value of the DefInputOpenOption queue attribute.
            int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF;

            // creating destination
            MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);

            // specify the message options...
            MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions(); // default
            // MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE = The MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE option requests that an MQPUT or MQPUT1 operation
            // is completed without the application waiting for the queue manager to complete the call.
            // Using this option can improve messaging performance, particularly for applications using client bindings.
            pmo.options = MQConstants.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE;

            // create message
            MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
            // MQFMT_STRING = The application message data can be either an SBCS string (single-byte character set),
            // or a DBCS string (double-byte character set). Messages of this format can be converted
            // if the MQGMO_CONVERT option is specified on the MQGET call.
            message.format = MQConstants.MQFMT_STRING;
            message.writeString("<message>Hallo Vinh</message>");
            queue.put(message, pmo);
            queue.close();

            MQAsyncStatus asyncStatus = qMgr.getAsyncStatus();
            System.out.println("valor do asyncStatus: " + asyncStatus.putSuccessCount);

        } catch (MQException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Die Verbindung zum Message Broker mit den "
                    + "Eigenschaften {} und dem QueueManager {} konnte nicht hergestellt werden.", props, qManager, e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Fehler beim Schreiben der Message.", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                qMgr.disconnect();
            } catch (MQException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Die Verbindung konnte nicht geschlossen werden.", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Error that happens when I execute the program:

```
    23:47:34.255 [main] ERROR com.mkyong.MQClientTest - Die Verbindung zum Message Broker mit den Eigenschaften {hostname=localhost, port=1414, channel=WM.SVRCONN.001} und dem QueueManager QM1 konnte nicht hergestellt werden.
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Código de Conclusão '2', Razão '2540'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:255)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:450)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:487)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:97)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:194)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:874)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:822)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:764)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:200)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:979)
    at com.mkyong.MQClientTest2.main(MQClientTest2.java:33)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2540;AMQ9204: Conexão com o host 'localhost(1414)' rejeitada. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2540;AMQ9520: Canal não definido remotamente. [3=WM.SVRCONN.001      ]],3=localhost(1414),5=RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2314)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:562)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.MQCONNX_j(MQSESSION.java:916)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:240)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2540;AMQ9520: Canal não definido remotamente. [3=WM.SVRCONN.001      ]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment(RemoteConnection.java:4464)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.receiveTSH(RemoteConnection.java:3199)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.initSess(RemoteConnection.java:1274)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:895)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:416)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:312)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1761)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mkyong.MQClientTest2.main(MQClientTest2.java:71)
```

Below I put the Image from the place where I configure the channel.

[image]

After deleting all queue managers and recreating a new one, I got this new error:

```
    com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Código de Conclusão '2', Razão '2035'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:255)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:450)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:487)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:97)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:194)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:874)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:822)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:764)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:200)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:979)
    at com.mkyong.MQClientTest2.main(MQClientTest2.java:33)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mkyong.MQClientTest2.main(MQClientTest2.java:73)
```

Directory where I installed IBM MQ:

[image]

After executing the comand set|findstr MQ:

```
    Classpath=C:\LINGO64_17\Lingo17.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mqjms.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib\com.ibm.mq.jar
CP=D:\rabbitMQ
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\c\include;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\cplus\include
LIB=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\lib64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\lib
MQ_FILE_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ
MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ
MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java
MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib
MQ_JRE_PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\jre
Path=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib64;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\PostgreSQL\pg95\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Progress\DataDirect\Connect64_for_ODBC_71\drivers;C:\Program Files\Progress\DataDirect\Connect64_for_ODBC_71\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\Progress\DataDirect\Connect64_for_ODBC_71\jre\bin\server;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\LINGO64_17\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\PostgreSQL\pg96\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\c\samples\bin64;C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\tools\c\samples\bin;C:\Users\camar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\camar\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;
```

Answer (score 0):

> MQJE001: Código de Conclusão '2', Razão '2540'.

Did you look up Reason Code 2540?  All MQ Reason Codes are documented in the MQ Knowledge.  Here is RC of [2540 (MQRC_UNKNOWN_CHANNEL_NAME)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q045400_.htm)

Here is the page with ALL of the [MQ Reason Codes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q040710_.htm).

In your sample, you used port # 1414 but you have 3 queue managers on your PC.  You were probably connecting to the wrong port, hence wrong queue manager.  If you don't remember the port # that you set for the queue manager, all you had to do was click on 'Listeners' and see what port # the 'LISTENER.TCP' object was using for that particular queue manager.  Every queue manager requires a UNIQUE port #.

So basically, you shot yourself in the foot by deleting your queue manager when you were NOT paying attention to what you were doing.

> MQJE001: Código de Conclusão '2', Razão '2035'.

Did you look up Reason Code 2035?  Here is RC of [2035 (MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041060_.htm)

Are you using the correct port # for the new queue manager? Did you create your channel in the new queue manager?  Are you using a SYSTEM.* channel or running under with a UserId in the 'mqm' group because the CHLAUTH backstop rule may be blocking you.  Read Morag's posting about CHLAUTH backstop rules:

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/websphere_mq_chlauth_the_back_stop_rule?lang=en
- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/chlauth_allow_some_privileged_admins?lang=en

Comment: should I open another question in stackoverflow to solve this remote access?

Comment: Yes don't mix questions as it will confuse people looking for answers. Also, if the UserId is in the 'mqm' group then it is considered an MQAdmin account!!!!!

Comment: there is no user in the mqm group.